# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/primefaces/event/CellEditEvent

Tags: jsf, primefaces, noclassdeffounderror

I have a DataTable - Cell Editing , i use the first one in primefaces showcase which called In-Cell Editing  , but when i run my JBoss 7 server i found an error

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/primefaces/event/CellEditEvent
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_02]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2427) [rt.jar:1.6.0_02]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1791) [rt.jar:1.6.0_02]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndex.<init>(ClassReflectionIndex.java:65) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:66) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 10 more
```

and i really don't understand what does this mean or what  should i change !!

Comment: Make sure that you are using compatible versions of primefaces and jsf. I think that could be a reason

Comment: i use JSF 2.0 and primefaces 4.0  they are compatible i think.

Comment: You don't actually have PrimeFaces 4.0 in runtime classpath. This exception is evident for this. If you tell in detail how exactly you upgraded PrimeFaces (your previous question mentions that you were initially using 3.3), then we can point out your mistake in this.

Comment: ok , i slected Referenced Libraries-->Configure build path--> Java build path : i removed Primefaces 3.3 and added Primefaces 4.0 as an external jar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments:

> *i slected Referenced Libraries-->Configure build path--> Java build path : i removed Primefaces 3.3 and added Primefaces 4.0 as an external jar*

This is definitely not the right way. That part only configures compiletime dependencies, not webapp runtime dependencies. In general, for starters who are still unable to create, build and deploy a WAR file in command console form top of head without using any book, IDE or build tools, do **not** ever touch the project's *Build Path* property or you may mess things because of lack of understanding of "under the covers" workings.

The right way is to open the webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib` folder, remove the physical `primefaces-3.3.jar` file from there and drop the physical `primefaces-4.0.jar` file in there. That's all. The IDE will then automatically do all the necessary magic in *Build Path*. No need to manually fiddle around there.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, But I resolved by adding **Primefaces.jar** in directory **web-inf/lib**